# Android Eclipse: Change the text in the app to a string created withing the program

Tags: android, eclipse, string, text

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39101/0/page/2

I have followed this tutorial and got it to work and everything. now i am working on my own stuff after getting the basics down. I dont understand though how i can change the text (above the part the user inputs their name) so a string that i have defined withing the .java file. I want to be able to change it so its like a question, the person will type the answer and hit the button, then it will say if it is correct or not. Then i will load a new string into the app and continue that process. Any ideas on how to just get text out there that i can change by just setting it equal to a new string or something like that?

EDIT:
My code right now is very sloppy, i have some random code in there commented out along with phsuedo code and all that jazz, it is unreadable if you are not me atm.

I guess my question is, How can i get a string that i create in the .java file to show up on the app UI? example:
String str = "Hello there!";
**output str into UI**

Comment: It seems you need to register to read that article. If you can paste the code you are writing, that will help in answering your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i get a string that i create in the .java file to show up on
>   the app UI?

I'm assuming you want to display it in a `TextView`. If so, you can do the following:

```
String str = "Hello there!";
private TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
text.setText(str);
```

Comment: Yup, thats it. That setText is what i was looking for, i dont understand why i could not find that in a google search. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*How can i get a string that i create in the .java file to show up on the app UI?*

In Android, anything that visualises somthing to the user is called a View. There are lots of different types, suitable for visualising different types of data. For basic text you will need a `TextView`. So simplify things, let's just assume that you have the XML code as presented in your link:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

There are numerous resources that explain how to you build/use layouts, their pros, cons and what not, so I'm skipping that part. The important thing to realise is that there is a `TextView` defined in the layout presented above. In order to reference it, it will need to have a unique id. Let's add one:

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/question_textview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
/>
```

You can then reference this TextView from Java code as follows:

```
TextView questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_textview);
```

Note that `R.id.question_textview` is basically what we named the TextView in the layout earlier. From here on, you have a Java object that you can do all sorts of things with, including getting and settings the text it is showing.

```
String textDisplayed = questionTextView.getText(); // This will get the text currently displaying.
questionTextView.setText("Please display me"); // This will set the displayed text to "Please display me".
```

I would really advise you to go through some more tutorials and api demos, as this is really basic stuff.

Comment: I know this is basic stuff. I however do like to play with stuff myself and figure out what i can. I only started doing this last night (i mainly just did basic c++, never done java before). I am bored over winter break so thought i would find something to take up my time. **BTW, this was really helpful too, thank you**