# How do you display a string on Android?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

**Edit:** it turned out the XML Viewer *wasn't* the emulator, and does not actually run code.

So, I'm starting my first app in Android Studio 1.1.0, and I realized that I can't even manage to display a string (created in the java file).

I did all research I could, but no matter what snippets of code I copy/paste, it never works.

I tried copy/pasting the snippet of code from the first answer here: [Android Eclipse: Change the text in the app to a string created withing the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661384/android-eclipse-change-the-text-in-the-app-to-a-string-created-withing-the-prog) and it doesn't work. The findViewById method is in red, and so is my_text_view :

```
String displaythisgoddammit = "display this goddammit";
    private TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    text.setText(displaythisgoddammit);
```

And my textview (in activity_main.xml) is:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/displaythisgoddammit"/>
```

It can't find the string, no matter what I do. Apparently I must put it in the strings.xml file, but then how do I edit it...? In the question I linked, the snippet of code apparently worked for a string in the java file.

Here is my main file (I'm not sure if it's really relevant though, it's just snippets of code I copy/pasted): http://pastebin.com/7uuHyJWP I put the string at line 144, should I put it elsewhere?

Some help please? I've been researching for 5 hours but none of the solutions I tried work...

Comment: At least post the code for your main activity. This will show us where and how you are attempting to set the text. My guess is you're setting it in a place in the application lifecycle such that the display is not being updated. But without seeing any code, that's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: "I did all research I could, but no matter what snippets of code I copy/paste, it never works."
Copying and pasting code, specially if you do not know what it does, is a bad idea.

Comment: Check your entire layout (post it here please).

Comment: Here you go guys (see edit). Emmanuel: I know what it does, it's just that it doesn't work at all. J Steven: you were right, I put it at the root, now that I've put it elsewhere it at least shows some colors.

Comment: @Zezombye Emmanual is right though, you've copied and pasted stuff in ways that puts your code in a very uncompilable (new word) fashion.

Comment: is `public void onCreate;(Bundle savedInstanceState;) ` inside another method? Because it looks like it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is very confusing and needs to be re-written/broken up. You posted a file with multiple classes, methods inside methods, and it's almost impossible to see what is what.

Comment: Ignore what I put in the file, what I want to know is just why the snippet of code I linked doesn't work at all. I just want to display a string in a textview.

Comment: *"Ignore what I put in the file,"* if it should be ignored then it shouldn't be in your post. Still, it is very confusing of what you have. Start with something simple (One Activity and one xml file) after you get that then you can move on to more complicated stuff.

Comment: Well, I was asked to put the file, so I put it. But even when I start a new project, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with your code is on the line when you use

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(id.my_text_view);
```

It is occuring because when you define a TextView or any other object by it's Id you need to use R.id.my_text_view.

So, to fix it simply change it to

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code please check the reference to the TextView that you are making.

It should be `findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);`

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO.

Comment: Did realize that, thank you Emmanuel and ngoa. It's my first time contributing and didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you should check:

- Inside a method, you should not be using the word `private`, as you are not defining a class level variable.
- You need to use `R.` before the id, to signify you are retrieving a resource.
- You need to make sure that the Text View is inside activity_main.xml.

In addition to all of that, you have **a lot** of things wrong in your pastebin file, I highly recommend you avoid just copy and pasting code, because it is never that simple.

You need to remove all access modifiers that are not at the class level, and clean up snippets like this:

```
String contentAsString;
    public void onCreate;(Bundle savedInstanceState;) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    txtwidth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewwidth);
    hello="This is my first project";


    mybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    txtView.setText(hello);}
```

There are brackets and semi colons all over the place, and not to mention this code is written *after* a return statement, so you won't even hit this line of code.

**NOTE**

Other things that I've found that are wrong:

- You have an extra closing bracket after the `DownloadWebpageTask` which will cause some compilation errors.
- You override `onCreate` twice in `HTTPExample`
- It looks like the code you're having trouble with should be inside onCreate.

In other words, try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/AdamMc331/d67bf84106b854f26e04).

- Also, inside your XML where you have the line `android:text="@string/displayThis`, the @string is basically saying you want to get the string 'displayThis' from strings.xml. If you don't have, or don't want to put 'displayThis' in strings.xml, you need to remove that attribute and just set the text programatically.

Comment: I know, much of this is commentary, but a comment can only have 600 characters...

Comment: Yeah, I know that lots of things in my pastebin file are wrong, but it's more experimental than anything. For now I'm just trying to display a string defined in a java file. Removing the "private" and adding the R doesn't change anything, and the text view is in activity_main.xml.

Comment: @Zezombye if that's all you want to do, you don't need an entire HTTP example activity class, just open a new `Hello World` activity in Android Studio and try adding in a button and some text. Start small, and build your way up, it's a lot better long term.

Comment: Yeah, the HTTP activity class is just because I want to download data from a web server. Anyway, I also tried the tutorials, and basically I have the same problem as this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647803/how-do-i-display-a-string-in-an-android-app The string referenced in the textview checks if it exists in the strings.xml, not in the MainActivity.java, so no matter where I put the string, it won't recognize it.

Comment: @Zezombye that happens because in your XML file, when you use `@string` you're signifying that you want to get something from strings.xml, if you don't want to do it like that, and you want to do it programatically, remove the android:text attribute, and just set it in `onCreate` like in my example.

Comment: I copy/pasted your onCreate, and it still doesn't work, it doesn't display anything this time. I also removed the android:text attribute. Android Studio puts textView, layout_main, my_text_view and myText in red.